# Python and Impala

Tags: python, stored-procedures, impala

I have a significant number of standardized queries that I run regularly in Impala for reporting purposes... just changing an ID and date range with each run. I'd like to automate this as much as possible such that I can run one script and save the results in csv in designated location.

The data is in Impala. Is it possible to do this within Impala by way of something like a stored procedure? If not, is it possible to do via Python?

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Impala does not have stored procedures yet, but you can use Python.

Take a look at [Impyla](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla) ([blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/a-new-python-client-for-impala/)) and [Ibis](https://github.com/cloudera/ibis) ([blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/07/ibis-on-impala-python-at-scale-for-data-science/)). Impyla is a simple Python client which provides the standard Python DB API while Ibis provides a [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)-like experience.